# Use pass by reference in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, reference

```
int f(int &x, int c) 
{
     c  = c - 1;
     if (c == 0) return 1;
     x = x + 1;
     return f(x, c) * x;
} 

int x = 5;
cout << f(x,5);
```

In the example above the four possible answers to choose from are:

1. 3024
2. 6561
3. 55440
4. 161051

Function `f(int &x, int c)` is called four times after the first call before it reaches the base case where it returns the result which is `6561`. My guess was `3024` but I was wrong. Even if the `x` variable which is passed by reference increments in each call of `f(int &x, int c)` and takes the values `6->7->8->9` respectively the final result of this recursion is equal to `9^4`.

So my question is: Variable `x` is passed by reference and is equal to `9` when it reaches the base case. Does that mean that all the stages of recursion will have this value for variable `x` even if they had a different value when they've been called?

Comment: I think UB as `f(x, c) * x;` modifies and also uses `x`. Unwinding a single round of recursion it simplifies to `++x * x` which is definitely UB.

Comment: @RichardCritten - Technically it's just *unspecified* behaviour, as there are sequence points around the function call.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thanks for the clarification, I was (still am) unsure of the correct terminology.

Comment: @RichardCritten - indeed, it's arcane!  "Undefined" means literally anything could happen (which is the case with `++x * x`).  "Unspecified" means that one of a finite number of things could happen (two in this case), but the standard doesn't specify which.  Of course, in practice, "undefined" and "unspecified" are equivalently bad.

Comment: Since it's passed by reference, the name "x" always refers to the same object, so a change in one function call will affect the others. (As this example shows, shared mutable state and recursion is a nasty combination.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Are you sure? In the expression `f(x, c) * x`, the evaluation of the two subexpressions of `*` is unsequenced, isn't it? So there are multiple unsequenced accesses of `x`.

Comment: @KerrekSB - There are two things - the evaluation order of `a * b` is unspecified, and there are also no sequence points.  But the function call itself (containing the modification of `x`) does have a sequence point.  So we're simply left with two possible evaluation orders (as listed in SamV's answer below).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I'm not sure. [intro.execution]/15 says that, unless otherwise stated, evaluation of operands is unsequenced. It doesn't matter than one of the operands is a well-defined expression; the evaluation of the two operands is what's unsequenced.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah, what I wrote is true in the pre-C++11 world.  I'm not sure how this is affected by the change of terminology in C++11 and later.  Though I **think** that "*Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.*" is equivalent.

Comment: This question is missing half the question. The four possible answers to **what**? Do you have the starting conditions?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I think what you've cited applies to something like `f(g(), g(), g())`. But for operator expressions, `g() @ g()`, a different rule is needed (the one I cited).

Comment: @KerrekSB - This debate is an illustration of why "unspecified" == "undefined" in practice ;)  I think it still applies to `f @ g()` - from the POV of `g()`, `f` is evaluated in the calling function.  It's not specifically sequenced (indeed it's unsequenced), so the cited clause states that it therefore becomes indeterminately sequenced.

Comment: @Barry Thank you for pointing that out. The starting conditions are x=5, c=5

Comment: Actually i apologize to all of you for not mentioning the starting conditions.

Answer (score 9):

No, there are more than four answers to choose from.

The fetch of `x` for the recursive function call, and the fetch of `x` for the right hand side of multiplication, is not sequenced with each other; and as such the evaluation order is unspecified.

This doesn't mean that the evaluation order would be some particular evaluation order, and it's only necessary to figure it out. This means that the final results can:

1. Vary depending on the compiler.
2. Vary each time this program executes.
3. The evaluation order may also be different for each individual recursive call. Each recursive call can end up using a different evaluation order, too. "Unspecified" means "unspecified". Any possibility can happen. Each individual time.

I didn't bother to calculate all actual possibilities here. It's better to invest one's own time on something that should work properly, instead of on something that obviously can never work properly.

If you want a specific evaluation order, it's going to be either this:

```
int y=x;

return f(x, c) * y;
```

Or this:

```
int y=f(x, c);

return y * x;
```

This evaluation order is now specified.