# Use of reference variables in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, reference, pass-by-reference

I came across the following question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int &x, int c)
{
    c  = c - 1;
    if (c == 0) return 1;
    x = x + 1;
    return f(x, c) * x;
}
int main()
{
    int p = 5;
    printf("%d", f(p, p));
}
```

As far as I have worked out, the recursion calls should work, and with each recursion call, value of c should reduce by 1 and value of x should increase by 1 . However, if I calculate it that way, the answer comes out to be 3024. However, on executing, the output comes out to be 6561. I am not really sure how this answer is coming.

I have the link to the article from where this question is taken, but I fail to understand how x will remain constant as is described in this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-references-question-1/

Can someone help me with the working behind this code?

Comment: Try stepping through with a debugger, or adding output statements (https://ideone.com/uoO3Ak) to watch the value of `c` and `x` each recursive function call.

Comment: Wouldn't the return value depend on whether `f(x, c)` or `x` gets evaluated first in `return f(x, c) * x`?

Comment: This is undefined behavior, because `x` is modified in one operand of the multiplication and read in the other operand.

Comment: This question which has been answered before in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933101/use-pass-by-reference-in-recursion

Comment: @MathiasJ That's operator precedence in the sense of figuring out where implicit parentheses go, it doesn't tell you anything about which order the operands get evaluated in.

Comment: @NathanPierson you are ofc. right. Miss read the response.

Answer (score 1):

There can be any result, due to [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Since the `x` is passed by reference, the last assign will matter. Thus, we have:

```
9*9*9*9*1=6561
```

We delay the evaluation of the `f(x, c) * x`, where all the subsequent recursive calls will have access to the `x`. We increment the `x` this way until the `c` is equal to `0`, means we increment the `x` up to it being `9`.

When we hit the base case (the `c == 0`), the current call returns `1`, while the `x` is already `9`.

Then we evaluate the multiplication `1 * x * x * x * x`, where `x` is equal to `9`. Thus, the `6561`.

Flawless explanation? **Not so much**.

The fun part is that **there is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C++**:

> Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of
> evaluation of function arguments is unspecified (with some exceptions
> listed below). The compiler can evaluate operands and other
> subexpressions in any order, and may choose another order when the
> same expression is evaluated again.

Means, that though this logic gets a pass this time, it may won't be this way next time for me or if you run it yourself.

Comment: The UB should be more visibility called out. Geekforgeek is harmful enough as it is, if we start copying their code without calling out UB...

Comment: @Jeffrey was afraid that the "set up and punchline" would not work out. Wait a minute.

Comment: Love the bold! much better.

Comment: As the duplicate gets into, I don't think this is actually _undefined_ behavior, but the evaluation of the operands is indeterminately sequenced so there's multiple possible values it could return. Still a big difference between "it can return exponentially many possibilities" and "literally any program behavior is acceptable".

Comment: @NathanPierson yeah, if it was possible to follow the logic, it leans towards being a case of what's called as *unspecified behavior*.